# Appending data to a csv file from a php form but also adding static data every time

Tags: php, csv

Ok I almost have it working but am having trouble escaping the html to preserve the link I'm missing something here .. I'm sure it's simple

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")

    $varUserName = $_POST['username'];

    $varPW = $_POST['PW'];

    $varEmail = $_POST['email'];

    {

        $fs = fopen("testcsv.csv","a");

        fputcsv($fs, array($varUserName,$varPW,$varEmail,"admin","title",",category","some text here <a href=""http://$varUserName.site.com/splash/"">site.com</a>",));

        fclose($fs);

        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show us your code

Comment: Add an example of the file before the user enters the data, and how you would like it to look after it has been written to.

Comment: I will do that if the suggestions so far don't put me on the right path.. thanks

Comment: and like a total moron I changed the post.. lol doh!

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure what you're having trouble with.  Are you familiar with fopen();?  Are you familiar with CSV?

You will need to open the file for appending and append to your file using fwrite().  Once done, close the file with fclose().

```
$fp = fopen("./filename", 'a');  //Open file for append
//fwrite($fp, $row1.",".$row2); //Append row,row to file
fputcsv($fp, array($name,$password,"http://$name.whatever.com")); //@Optimist
fclose($fp); //Close the file to free memory.
```

Comment: `fputcsv()` much preferred to `fwrite()` for csv data.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I'm able to get the form input into the csv fine.  I'm just a little confused on how to add the required content to that input.  It will be the same text every time, just need to add the input from the form to required text on every line.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. If you are able to write to the file, are you wondering about how to concatenate strings? Use that example and change the second line to `fputcsv($fp, array($name,$password,"http://$name.whatever.com"));`

Comment: so it writes the csv file if I take out the html part.. but i need the html code to be in the csv.. how do I escape the "'s in the html to make it work?

Comment: @user1207458 I just ran across this in search of another issue, but to answer your question (assuming you want one this late in the game), instead of trying to escape double quotes here - use single quotes instead. Otherwise, if yuo must use double quotes, you can escape them by doing the following `"\"http://blah.com/\""`